# Rotating a multiline string 90 degrees - lines become columns

Tags: c#, string, unicode

Say I have a string like

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

I want to turn this string 90 degrees clockwise, so that it becomes

```
LL
ii
nn
ee

12
```

The rotation needs to be performed only once such that it is in effect 'turning lines into columns.' Performing it twice should give the original string. (If it was truly rotating by 90 degrees, it would have to be repeated four times to arrive back at the original.)

Comment: Isn't this question better suited for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) rather than StackOverflow? Judging from both the OP and the answers it has attracted so far...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It will need to add leading spaces (i.e. columns which were preceding shorter lines in the original string.) This method gives you an option to make this visible (`fillChar` - several options provided as constants.)

Also the additional `ReverseLineOrder` method reverses the line order in case you would want to rotate 90 degrees, reversing all lines.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace Library.Text
{
    public static class TextRotate
    {
        public const char Space = ' ';
        public const char MiddleDot = '\u00b7';
        public const char Circle = '\u25cb';
        public const char BlackSquare = '\u25a0';
        public const char NoBreakSpace = '\u00a0';

        public static string LinesToColumns(string s, char fillChar = Space)
        {
            // A line feed at the end of the text is not seen as content.
            // However, if the text ends in a line feed, we make sure the output ends in one, too.

            bool endsWithNewline = s.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine);

            string[] linesIn = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            int[][] textElements = new int[linesIn.Length][];

            int longestLine_chars = 0;
            int longestLine_elems = 0; // The longest line, in text elements

            for (int l = 0; l < linesIn.Length; l++)
            {
                string line = linesIn[l];

                if (line.Length > longestLine_chars)
                {
                    longestLine_chars = line.Length;
                }

                var elems = StringInfo.ParseCombiningCharacters(line); // Gets indices of surrogate pairs, combining characters etc.

                if (elems.Length > longestLine_elems)
                {
                    longestLine_elems = elems.Length;
                }

                textElements[l] = elems;
            }

            // Go through columns (columns in the input text, and columns in terms of text elements - NOT chars)

            string[] columns = new string[longestLine_elems];

            var builder = new StringBuilder(longestLine_chars * linesIn.Length + Math.Max(longestLine_chars, linesIn.Length) * Environment.NewLine.Length);

            for (int column = 0; column < longestLine_elems; column++)
            {
                builder.Clear();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(builder.Length == 0);
                int cutoff = 0;

                for (int l = 0; l < linesIn.Length; l++)
                {
                    // Is the line long enough to reach to this column?

                    int[] lineTextElements = textElements[l];
                    int textElementsInLine = lineTextElements.Length;

                    if (textElementsInLine > column)
                    {
                        int firstCharIndex = lineTextElements[column];

                        if (column + 1 < textElementsInLine)
                        {
                            int nrOfChars = lineTextElements[column + 1] - firstCharIndex;
                            builder.Append(linesIn[l], firstCharIndex, nrOfChars);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            builder.Append(linesIn[l], firstCharIndex, linesIn[l].Length - firstCharIndex);
                        }

                        cutoff = builder.Length;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        builder.Append(fillChar);
                    }
                }

                // Trim the fill char off line endings (for when rotating back)
                while (cutoff > 0 && builder[cutoff - 1] == fillChar)
                {
                    cutoff--;
                }

                // Resulting column
                columns[column] = builder.ToString(0, cutoff);
            }

            // Turn the columns into lines
            builder.Clear();

            foreach (var c in columns)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(c);
            }

            if (!endsWithNewline && builder.Length > 0)
            {
                builder.Length -= Environment.NewLine.Length;
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public static string ReverseLineOrder(string s)
        {
            // A line feed at the end of the text is not seen as content.
            // However, if the text ends in a line feed, we make sure the output ends in one, too.

            bool endsWithNewline = s.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine);

            string[] linesIn = s.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            var builder = new StringBuilder(s.Length);

            for (int l = linesIn.Length - (endsWithNewline ? 2 : 1); l >= 0; l--)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(linesIn[l]);
            }

            if (!endsWithNewline && builder.Length > 0)
            {
                builder.Length -= Environment.NewLine.Length;
            }

            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want `StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator()` or similar to handle user-perceived characters that aren't made only of base+combining chars, e.g. emoji

Comment: This look awfully long for something that should take about 10 lines

Comment: Franck, write your code so that it is understandable for others and for yourself at any time in the future.

Comment: @Tavian Barnes It's a consideration, yes. But I think that method you mention does not do that (if you mean text emoticons, like :)

Comment: No I mean things like  or ‍‍‍ which are made out of multiple non-combining characters (https://emojipedia.org/emoji-flag-sequence/, https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequence/)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace rotateString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strings = new string[] { "Line 1", "Line 2" };

            var lines = new List<string>();

            var done = false;
            var j = 0;
            do
            {
                var line = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < strings.Length; ++i)
                {
                    var s = strings[i];
                    if (j >= s.Length)
                    {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    line += s[j];
                }
                lines.Add(line);
                ++j;
            } while (!done);

            for(int i=0; i < lines.Count; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : '{1}'", i, lines[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 : 'LL'
1 : 'ii'
2 : 'nn'
3 : 'ee'
4 : '  '
5 : '12'
6 : ''
```

Note that this pretty much assumes the strings are all the same length. Adjusting it to work with the longest string length is trivial.

Using a `StringBuilder` would be a bit more efficient but, unless you're working with a lot of very long strings, you'll never see the difference in performance.

Comment: @KayZed It does not fail on Windows or MacOS. What compiler are you using? Works fine on Visual Studio. And, your question said nothing about unicode.

Comment: @KayZed in no way Dave solution should give you any issues. It's just shifting char around. It does not change them in any ways. I can understand a EOF char might cause problem but otherwise this should work 100% of the time.

Comment: Except for that, it's a good solution, works. I like it.

Comment: The tag says unicode. It's also tagged C# - you didn't miss that. Look up any string answers in .NET. Unicode all the way.

Comment: @KayZed Incorrect in just about every way. Just tagging something `unicode` is pointless unless your question actually includes something about unicode. If you don't like the answer, fine. Downvote it. The VAST majority of production C# code doesn't have to deal with unicode.

Comment: Wow, you must be in an alternate world, posting from the 90s, or a niche business working with older systems. Almost all questions on C# strings are peppered with "does not handle combining characters" comments and the like. That last sentence really does it, haha.

Comment: @KayZed Whatever, man. Ask a proper question and you'll get the response you're looking for. The technique is identical either way. You just need to deal with the byte array rather than expecting 8-bit characters. Forgive me for assuming that you're capable of googling and didn't expect us to write your code for you. Your statement about "almost all questions on C# strings" is demonstrably false.

Answer (score 0):

This was interesting to try out and write. I haven't spent time on validation and characters, but I was trying to see if I can write something that is somewhat "compact" (challenge to myself mostly in evening hours).

@KayZed I will also run your implementation, I see you did some more validations about the inputs.

@3Dave I see we had similar ideas about this ;)

My idea around this was a projection of the input strings (plus now I hard-coded the length of the `Span<char>`, that calculation can be made simple) into the "flattened" structure of all characters with the offset of the index based on the number of inputs.

My "solution":

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var inputs = new[] { "Short", "Line 1", "Line 2", "Much longer line 3", "" };
        
        Rotate(inputs);
    }

    public static void Rotate(IReadOnlyCollection<string> aValues)
    {
        Span<char> chars = stackalloc char[100];
        var offset = 0; 
        foreach (var value in aValues)
        {
            var index = 0;
            foreach (char character in value)
            {
                chars[index + offset] = character;
                index += aValues.Count;
            }
            offset++;
        }

        var position = 0;
        foreach (char character in chars)
        {
            Console.Write(character == default(char) ? ' ' : character);
            Console.Write(' ');

            if (position == aValues.Count - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                position = 0;
                continue;
            }

            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

I probably missed some edge cases (and didn't handle the "special" characters), but hope this gives an idea on some "optimisations".

The output:

```
S L L M � 
h i i u � 
o n n c   
r e e h   
t         
  1 2 l   
      o   
      n   
      g   
      e   
      r   
          
      l   
      i   
      n   
      e   
          
      3
```

Comment: Nice. Short, sweet and to the point. I also wasn't familiar with `stackalloc` before this. I think our C# implementation is a few revs behind.

Comment: Thanks. I also started playing with it recently. Was planning over weekend to write couple benchmarks and compare implementations. Also vs. StringBuilder & array, etc.

Comment: `StringBuilder` will only make a noticeable difference on *very* long strings. But, it's a good exercise in profiling, etc. Have fun!